# Verifying JWT not working with issuer-uri

Tags: spring, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to verify Firebase JWTs on my Spring Boot backend but I am confused about what is happening here.

This is what the JWT header looks like. Please note the `kid` (key ID):

```json
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "f4bb220cd094b0ae90dd73e10c10e7db54b89280",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

My question here is why is the `jwt-set-uri` approach working and why is it not working with the `issuer-uri` being set. Below you'll find my explanation why it is not working but I would like to know if this *should* work or not (because it *should* in my opinion).

I'd also like to understand the difference between the two.

### Using `jwt-set-uri`

After trial and error, after getting a bit mislead by [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library), I discovered that the verification works with Spring Boot if I just set [this URL](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs):

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

instead of https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com (or https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com) as suggested in the docs.

The JSON response of https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs currently looks like below. Please note the matching `kid` for the JWT header above.

```json
// 20220219131110
// https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

{
  "keys": [
    {
      // ..
      "kid": "f4bb220cd094b0ae90dd73e10c10e7db54b89280",
    },
    {
      // ..
      "kid": "acb6be51efea6a419ec9325feaa1ec4660f5b37c"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Using `issuer-uri`

Now, with this setting I am able to secure my Spring Boot application but I wonder why it is not working if I set the `issuer-uri` instead. [Acoording to this tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/#use-spring-security-to-authorize-the-request), we'll get a final URL `{issuer-uri}/.well-known/openid-configuration`, which in my case would be https://securetoken.google.com/project-id/.well-known/openid-configuration. However, if you look at this JSON you'll see the following content:

```json
// 20220219130800
// https://securetoken.google.com/project-id/.well-known/openid-configuration

{
  "issuer": "https://securetoken.google.com/project-id",
  "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com",
  "response_types_supported": [
    "id_token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ]
}
```

Please note the `jwks_uri` value which leads to [this JSON response](https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com):

```json
// 20220219130944
// https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid": "f24f3148197ecea52917c3f1838ab5d4887ea076",
      // ..
    },
    {
      "kid": "27dde1020020b78fb876d7b25ed8f0a9ce06db4d",
      // ..
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the `kid` does not match and as a consequence, JWT-verification does not work in Spring Boot.

Comment: There are types of RSA public keys for service accounts. The ones created by Google for your service account and the keys you created. The first URl is for Google created keys. The second is for the private keys you created when you downloaded the JSON key file.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi! Not sure if I fully get this though. Why for example are the keys the same for all project-ids? So these keys are not exclusive to my private keys?

Comment: I do not know the why just what they are. The point of verifying the signature is to know who signed the data, which in your case is Google. If you used your user-managed keys, then you signed the data.

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through a similar or the same problem when I configured issue-uri I received an error. I have fixed it by setting the issue-uri in quotes in my application.yaml. That was my problem after that everything worked fine, then remember to configure  OAuth 2.0 Resource Server support adding .oauth2ResourceServer() and
JWT Resource server support adding .jwt to SecurityWebFilterChain. At the end I leave my configuration as an example.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: example
  security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt:
    jwk-set-uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken%40system.gserviceaccount.com"
    issuer-uri: "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
```

With version:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>2.6.3</version>
```

And my SecurityWebFilterChain is:

```
@Bean
   SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeExchange()
             
         // any URL that starts with /admin/ requires the role "ROLE_ADMIN"
         .pathMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // OK

         // any other request requires the user to be authenticated and ENABLE
         .anyExchange()
         .hasRole("ENABLE")
         .and()
         .oauth2ResourceServer()
         .jwt();
      return http.build();
}
```

Comment: I feel like I am back to the start. It's always something.. Maybe you can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821394/spring-boot-firebase-failed-to-authenticate-since-the-jwt-was-invalid