# Spring Boot Firebase: Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid

Tags: spring-boot, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

> `Spring Boot: 3.0.4`

In order to validate JWT tokens from Firebase Auth, I have the follwing setup:

First, I am securing and configuring my routes like so:

```yaml
# application.yaml

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
          issuer-uri: "https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>"
```

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            (config) -> {
                try {
                    config
                            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/anon/**")).permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

and I am configuring the `FirebaseApp` like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FirebaseConfig.class);

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public FirebaseConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public FirebaseApp firebaseApp() throws IOException {

        LOGGER.info("Initializing Firebase.");
        String googleCredentials = environment.getProperty("GOOGLE_FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS");
        if (googleCredentials == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("GOOGLE_FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS not set.");
        }

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(googleCredentials);
        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }

        return FirebaseApp.getApps().get(0);
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("firebaseApp")
    public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

}
```

However, sending a request from my Angular App to the backend gives me the an error response in the `JwtAuthenticationProvider` stating "*Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid*".

```
2023-03-23T10:35:27.221+01:00 DEBUG 102007 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /hello-world
2023-03-23T10:35:27.221+01:00 DEBUG 102007 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
```

This here is the request header which, as you can see, has the `Authorization` set correctly which I have received using `AngularFire`

```js
private auth: Auth = inject(Auth);

public user$ = user(this.auth);

public idToken$ = idToken(this.auth);

constructor(
  private logger: NGXLogger,
) {
  this.subs.add(this.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user));
  this.subs.add(this.idToken$.subscribe(idToken => this.idToken = idToken}));
}
```

```http
GET /hello-world HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-AT;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer ey..<the-token>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8081
Origin: https://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

### The JWT

```json
// Header
{
  "alg": "none",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

// Body
{
  "name": "Raccoon Otter",
  "email": "raccoon.otter.271@example.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "auth_time": 1679558072,
  "user_id": "ieZuX2TRrJHOufqFjhpYTtXMcAsB",
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "email": [
        "raccoon.otter.271@example.com"
      ],
      "google.com": [
        "7776418049744228599441294898732774086098"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
  },
  "iat": 1679565375,
  "exp": 1679568975,
  "aud": "<project-id>",
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>",
  "sub": "ieZuX2TRrJHOufqFjhpYTtXMcAsB"
}

// Signature
<empty>
```

Comment: Do not use ID tokens as access tokens https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens

Comment: @ch4mp As stated in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients): "Firebase creates a corresponding ID token that uniquely identifies them and grants them access to several resources, .. You can re-use that ID token to identify the user or device on your custom backend server."